# Setting custom divider image in UITabBar using setDividerImage:forLeftState:rightState:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html

In the above link Images section "By default, there is no divider image between tabs on a tab bar. You can set custom divider images for each combination of left and right tab control states using the            setDividerImage:forLeftState:rightState:method. If you use custom dividers, make sure to set divider images all combinations of tabs states: left selected, right selected, or both unselected."

How can i use setDividerImage:forLeftState:rightState: method for setting custom divider in UITabBar?

I tried many options [UITabBar appearance], [UITabBarItem appearance], [UITabBarController appearance], self.tabBarController.tabBar and self.tabBarController.tabBarItem but xcode code completion didn't show me aforesaid method.

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 with iOS sdk 7.1.

Looking forward to hear from you guys!

Thanks & Regards,

Mihir

Comment: Nope haven't tried afterwards !

Comment: Seems like this is incorrect information from Apple.

Comment: Agree cant find it in the API